# where does linux store downloaded files from servers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to download a file from some server through the Ubuntu terminal using the below line code, and after the file is 100% downloaded, I cannot find it anywhere on my machine.

`scp username@ip:/path/filename .`

what can I do?

Comment: What is the remote path supposed to be?  `/path/file` or `/path/file name`?  Because currently your command is copying (a) a remote file called `/path/file` and (b) a local file called `name` to (c) the current directory (`.`).

Comment: I meant I used `scp username@ip:/path/filename .`  Just edited it in the question to avoid confusion .

Comment: After that `scp` command, you don't have a file called `filename` in the current directory?  If not, is there a _directory_ called `filename` containing your `filename` file?  Is there any output from `scp`?

Comment: `filename` is just an example for the sake of the question, it's not the real name of the file I'm trying to download.

Comment: I think we know that. Whatever the name of the file, if you used `.` as the destination for the file, it ought to be available in the current directory.  If there is a directory with the same name as the file, then the file may be in that directory.  If you used another target than `.`, then _please_ update your question with the actual command that you used.

Comment: when I run the code, I get in the terminal that the file is downloading and after it reaches 100%, I cannot find it on my machine.

Comment: Well, what can I say? The command that you show puts the file in the current directory. If there are other circumstances that make something else happen, you are not letting us know about them.

Comment: No, I used '.' as the destination and I still cannot find the downloaded file.

Comment: Does the _actual_ name of the file that you transfer start with a dot?

Comment: Nope, it starts with a number; it's called "6.root".

Comment: There are no permission issues? If you do `touch 6.root`, this creates an empty file with the correct name in the current directory? `scp` does not produce diagnostic messages saying _anything_?

Comment: No, it doesn't say anything. Could it be that the code copies the file to the same server instead of downloading it on my machine? When I use 'pwd' it shows the directory in the server (which is the current directory?), and when I use `.` in the code, it transfers the file to the current directory which is the server? does that make sense?

Comment: Um, no, that does not make sense. Why would `pwd` say that you are in a directory on the server? Did you `ssh` to the server? If you did, then you should use your "home system" as the target while specifying the source path locally on the server, alternatively simply log out of the remote server and use `scp` from your home system as you show in the question.

Comment: If you are logged in on the remote server and in the directory from which you want to transfer the file, then your command is effectively the same as `cp filename filename`, i.e. it copies the file to itself.

Answer (score 2):

You copied the file to the directory in which you ran the command. `.` means "the current directory".

Comment: And how can I copy it to my machine? because when I use `pwd` it shows the directory in the server.

Comment: When you run `scp user@host:/path/file .`, it copies a file from the machine `host` to the machine you run `scp` on. If you are running `scp` on the remote machine, that won't do you much good.

Comment: Maybe you’d have better luck using `sftp`, which lets you change your local cwd if you can’t figure out what’s going on. (`scp` is probably going away anyway)